# FancyBox popup loses all styling when loading Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I am trying to load a partial view in my MVC project using fancybox. It seems to load the content correctly. Most of it anyway as it seems to cut the page short, but it loses all styling from the view when it loads it.

I have included my CSS files in my partial view but still no luck.

My partial view is as follows:

```
@model ApprovalSystem.ViewModels.RequestDetailViewModel
@section styles
{
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
//CONTENT HERE - Not providing it all as it is quite large. Classes and all remain in the partial view though so cannot see that being an issue.
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
        })
    </script>    
}
```

My link to open the fancybox is:

```
<a data-fancybox href="@Url.Action("DetailPartial", new { id = Model.Request.ParentRequestId })" class="mui-btn mui-btn--fab mui-btn--small fancybox.ajax">@Model.Request.ParentRequestId</a>
```

And the controller method to return the partial view is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DetailPartial(int id)
{
    var request = _uow.RequestService.Get(id);
    var currentUser = await AzureGraph.GetUser();
    ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser.DisplayName;
    ViewBag.NextApprover = _uow.ResponseService.Get().Where(r => r.RequestId == id && r.ResponseStatus == RequestStatus.NotProcessed).Select(r => r.Responder).FirstOrDefault();
    RequestDetailViewModel viewModel = new RequestDetailViewModel()
    {
        Request = request
    };

    if (request.FolderId != null)
        viewModel.Attachments = await AzureGraph.GetFileSystemObjects(request.FolderId);
    else
        viewModel.Attachments = new List<FSObject>();

    return PartialView("DetailPartial", viewModel);
}
```

I am all out of ideas and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - Added screenshot**

[image]

Comment: screenshot ????????

Comment: @SahilDhir added screenshot to question

Comment: It also loses all formatting if i just navigate to the partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this. The issue was that because the partial view had no layout, sections werent being loaded correctly. So i created a basic layout for partial views and it now works as expected.